# Плагин jQuery Waypoints не работает

Tags: javascript, jquery, плагин

Скачала плагин jQuery Waypoints. Не понимаю, как подключить. Всё перепробовала, он всё равно не работает. Видимо, я туплю, но как его подключить-то? Допустим просто для проверки хочу проскроллить до какого-нибудь элемента и вызвать `alert( 'Hello')`. Что для этого нужно написать?

Comment: Покажите как подключаете и почему вы думаете, что не работает?

Comment: `<script src="/path/to/noframework.waypoints.min.js"></script>` :)

Comment: @Nick так и делала, окей) по шагам: подключила, теперь допустим просто для проверки хочу проскроллить до какого-нибудь элемента и вызвать alert( 'Hello'). Что для этого нужно написать?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var waypoints = $('.boom').waypoint(function(direction) {
    alert('boom hit top')
  })
})
```

```css
.boom {
  padding: 50px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 10px 0 0;
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>

<div class=top>
  scroll down
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br> scroll down
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br> scroll down
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br> scroll down
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br> scroll down
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br> scroll down
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
<div class=boom>BOOOOM</div>
```